# Popular datagrid com threading

Tags: c#, winforms, thread, datagridview

Estou contraindo uma aplicação Windows Form. Não estou conseguindo popular meu `datagrid` com uma *threading*, aparece o seguinte erro:

> "Operação entre threads inválida: controle datagrid acessado de um thread que na é aquela no qual foi criado

Comment: Facilite a ajuda, coloque o código. Veja também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

Um elemento de tela UI(controle), no Winforms e WPF nao permitem ser acessados por outras threads ou múltiplas threads.

O elemento UI apenas pode ser acessado pela thread que nela foi criada.

O que voce pode fazer é utilizar delegates...

```
Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
     if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex < dataGridView1.RowCount )
     {
          dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Selected = false;
          dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1].Selected = true;
     }
}));
```